# Ubuntu 10.04 LTS hangs at 43% of preparing to partition raid 1drives

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, raid1

I have set up hardware raid 1 with two SAS drives using the Adptec 6405E controller. I am having a problem when installing Ubuntu 10.04 LTS  as it hangs at 43 % when partitioning disk drives. So far my Googling suggests that Ubuntu does not scan raided drives well. What can I do to finish my installation?